# Showing console with Spring Boot, Gradle and IDEA

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

Working through setting up a spring boot project with gradle and Idea.  I created a Run configuration calling the bootRun gradle task.  It appears to run fine (I can hit the end point) but I dont see the same console output (I don't see any) that I see when I run ./gradlew bootRun from a terminal.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to toggle `(/ab)`  below debug button(**left side of console**). See this picture..

[image]

Comment: Wow I feel dumb.

Comment: @gunygoogoo Be kind to yourself; as good as intellj is there's a lot crammed into the UI. It's always worth scanning and mousing over every icon at the edge of each window to find useful icons and error indicators.